# How to execute consecutive if statements after one has completed from single function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I am trying to connect to 3 api's but from one button click essentially - and I want each process to start after the previous has finished. However, currently it just executes the first if statement and does not run the next two.

Is their a different approach I should take?

```
    const syncAccount = () => {
        if(!mavenlinkConnected){
            getMavenlinkAuthorization()
        }
        if (!bambooConnected){
            authorizeBamboo();
        }
        if (!maconomyConnected){
            authorizeMaconomy();
        }
    }
```

Below is the other functions that are in relation to the above code block

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) return;
        if (!user) return navigate("/");
        fetchUserName();

        if(userTokenCode !== null){
            authorizeMavenlink();
        }
    }, [user, loading]);


    const authorizeMavenlink = () => {
        console.log(uid);
        const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/oauth/mavenlink?code='+userTokenCode,
            data: {}
        })
        .then((response) => {
            setAccessToken(response.data);
            setDoc(userRef, { mavenlinkAccessToken: response.data}, { merge: true });
            setMavenlinkConnected(true);
            setSuccessAlert(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setErrorAlert(true)
        });
    }

    const getMavenlinkAuthorization = () => {
        window.open('https://app.mavenlink.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=********&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000');
        window.close();
    }

    const authorizeBamboo = () => {
        // axios({
        //     method: 'post',
        //     url: 'http://localhost:5000/oauth/bamboo',
        //     data: {}
        // })
        // .then((response) => {
        //     console.log(response)

        // })
        // .catch((error) => {
        //     console.log(error);
        // });
        console.log('bamboo connected')
        setBambooConnected(true);
    }

    const authorizeMaconomy = () => {
        console.log("Maconomy connected")
        setMaconomyConnected(true);
    }
```

Comment: You can `await` for there response. Since you are calling an api then you can use `async-await`. But this is just a partial code, You should add full code so that people can understand your problem better

Comment: Tbh the issue is not anything to do with API's they have their separate function calls. I just want to know how to have an if statement execute - once done moves onto next.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you are calling API's on each if statement
You should mark your function as async and wait for each execution.
Example:-

```
const syncAccount = async() => {
        if(!mavenlinkConnected){
            await getMavenlinkAuthorization()
        }
        if (!bambooConnected){
            await authorizeBamboo();
        }
        if (!maconomyConnected){
            await authorizeMaconomy();
        }
    }
```

or you use promises

```
const syncAccount = () => {
        if(!mavenlinkConnected){
            getMavenlinkAuthorization().then({
                if (!bambooConnected){
                   return authorizeBamboo();
                } else {
                  return Promise.resolve();
                }
            }).then(() => {
                if (!maconomyConnected){
                   return authorizeMaconomy();
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                //log error
            })
        }
    }
```

Best of luck! Happy coding...